# Selenium Python - Wait for Element to load and click on it

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I've been trying to figure out how to wait for an element to be loaded and then execute the click function in python.

The website I am talking about is: https://tempail.com/

As soon as I received an e-mail, I want the script to click on it and then execute further tasks.

I tried to solve this problem through the "Try/Except Function", but I always receive error messages.

Source of the site:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2z6E.png

The problem is that the site uses generated IDs I can't use in the `find_element_by` function.

This is what I've tried so far:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlN6f.png

With try, I wanted the script to wait until the site received the mail. As soon as the mail is in the inbox, it should click the link/the mail and open it.

Apart from that, I looked up for more solutions, but nothing really helped out, but with this code I always receive the following error:

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".epostalar ul li.mail a"}
```

Plus it doesn't even wait for the mail.

Comment: Which link would you like to click? `TEMPAIL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as you receive an e-mail, to invoke `click()` on it you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul.mailler li.mail a"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='mailler']//li[contains(@class, 'mail')]//a"))).click()
  ```